# Why isn't this line printing to console?

Tags: r

I was writing a function for a random walk and I realized that a variable was not being printed by typing its name, only when I specified "print". The variable in concern is called "this".

```
rwalk = function(k) {
  this = sample(c(1,-1),k,TRUE,c(0.5,0.5))
  this
  x = append(c(0),cumsum(t))
  x
}
```

Above, only the value of x is printed.

```
rwalk = function(k) {
  this = sample(c(1,-1),k,TRUE,c(0.5,0.5))
  print(this)
  x = append(c(0),cumsum(t))
  x
}
```

Here both values are printed. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you ran `rwalk` without assigning the output to a variable

```
rwalk(3)
```

So `x` is returned to the global environment and printed because it is not assigned to a variable. This is the behavior of R. Typing `x` is equivalent to `print(x)` in the global environnment. However `this` lives in the environment of the function `rwalk`. There is no reason to print it until it is explicitly stated by the programmer. This is what you did with `print(this)`.

If you assign the output to a variable, nothing will be printed.

```
x <- rwalk(3)
```

The point is that your last `x` before the end of the function does not print anything. It states that the function returns `x`. It is only outside the function, once returned, that the value is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Without any kind of `return` statement, only the last line of output will be returned by a function by default, and only one object can be returned at a time. If you run something like

```
rwalk = function(k) {
  this = sample(c(1,-1),k,TRUE,c(0.5,0.5))
  return(this)
  x = append(c(0),cumsum(t))
  x
}
```

then only `this` will be returned. If you want to actually get `this` as an output (rather than just printing it) you will need to put it in a list with `x`.

```
rwalk = function(k) {
  this = sample(c(1,-1),k,TRUE,c(0.5,0.5))
  x = append(c(0),cumsum(t))
  list(this, x)
}
```